# Python replace characters in string

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port

Maybe I have trival issue but I can't find solution.
I use Raspberry Pi to read value from serial port. Input from serial looks like " b'1\r\n' ".
In this input I need only the number. I tried this code:

```
data = str(data)
data = data[2:7]
data = data.replace("\r\n","")
print(data)
```

Output of this code is : "1\r\n". I can't get rid of this part of string, replace function just doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `bytes` you can use the decode method of bytes to get back a string. you can then use `rstrip` method of str to remove the trailing new line chars.

```py
data = b'1\r\n'
print(data)
data = data.decode(('utf-8;')).rstrip()
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b'1\r\n'
1
```